# Select first record with aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, report, aggregates

I have a thermometer that starts logging data every morning whenever my machine turns on.

I would like to select the min, max, and average temperatures, as well as the temperatures when the machine turns on and off for every day.

My table structure is as follows:

Time Logged, Date Logged, Temperature

I group by Date Logged to get the aggregates for the day, but I can't seem to find a good way to select the temperature at the first and last time stamps recorded.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a windows function like this:

```
select t.DateLogged, min(t.Temperature), max(t.Temperature), avg(t.Temperature),
       max(case when t.seqnum_asc = 1 then t.Temperature end) as FirstTemperature,
       max(case when t.seqnum_desc = 1 then t.Temperature end) as LastTemperature,
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by dateLogged order by timeLogged) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by dateLogged order by timeLogged desc) as seqnum_desc
      from t
     ) t
group by t.DateLogged
order by DateLogged
```

What this is doing is adding two new variables.  One enumerates the values during the day starting at 1 with the first reading (`seqnum_asc`).  The other enumeration has 1`for the last reading (`seqnum_desc`).

To get the values, a conditional summation is used.

If you like, you can actually do pretty much the same thing using `min()` and `max()` as window fucnctions, rather than `row_number()`:

```
select t.DateLogged, min(t.Temperature), max(t.Temperature), avg(t.Temperature),
       max(case when timeLogged = mintime then t.Temperature end) as FirstTemperature,
       max(case when timeLogged = maxtime then t.Temperature end) as LastTemperature,
from (select t.*,
             min(timeLogged) over (partition by dateLogged) as minTime,
             max(timeLogged) over (partition by dateLogged) as maxTime
       from t
      ) t
group by t.DateLogged
order by DateLogged
```